# Afunction that take an input string 45A7 and return the next value like 45A8...45A9...45AA... alphabet is 1 to 9 and A to Z

Tags: php, algorithm

Here is a code that implement all but I want only get the next value of the input

$alphabet = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L','M', 'N','O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');

```
$premier = $alphabet;
$deuxieme = $alphabet;
$troisieme = $alphabet;
$quatrieme = $alphabet;
$cinquieme = $alphabet;
$sizieme = $alphabet;

for ($count1 = 0; $count1 <=count($alphabet); $count1++){
    for ($count2 = 0; $count2 <=count($alphabet); $count2++){
        for ($count3 = 0; $count3 <=count($alphabet); $count3++){
            for ($count4 = 0; $count4 <=count($alphabet); $count4++){
                for ($count5 = 0; $count5 <=count($alphabet); $count5++){
                    for ($count6 = 0; $count6 <=count($alphabet); $count6++){
                        echo ($premier[$count1].''. $deuxieme[$count2] .''.$troisieme[$count3] .''.$quatrieme[$count4] .''.$cinquieme[$count5].''. $sizieme[$count6].'<br>');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of possible interest: in Ruby, `"45k9".to_i(36).next.to_s(36) #=> "45ka"`.

Comment: And what's your question about this? Anything not working with the given code?

Answer (score 1):

FRANÇAIS : Bonjour, il y a une fonction base_convert() qui permet d'interpréter des chiffres selon la base voulue. Vous semblez utiliser un chiffre en base 36. Alors la solution simple serait de ramener le chiffre en base 10, l'incrémenter, et le remettre en base 36.

ENGLISH : Hi, there is a base_convert() function that translates a number to any base. You seem to use numbers in base 36. So the simplest solution would be to bring your number to base 10, increment it, and put it back to base 36.

```
$chiffre = base_convert($input, 36, 10);
$chiffre++;
echo base_convert($chiffre, 10, 36);
```

Documentation : [www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php)

Comment: Okey, let me try to implement that function in my program. Thank you #macq